# React Context API - Reducer editing whole object instead of its property

Tags: reactjs, react-context

So i have in my state an array of Posts each post is like this :

```
{
    "likes": 1,
    "comments": [],
    "_id": "5f3eb143167cbe1014ecdf3d",
    "user": {
        "_id": "5f39496b7e78810b801b3ff8",
        "name": "jon doe"
    },
    "title": "post 1",
    "img_url": "https://url.com",
    "date": "2020-08-20T17:22:11.324Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

And i have a function that likes the post in my actions , here it is :

```
    const postAddLike = async (id) => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.put(`/api/posts/like/${id}`)
            console.log(res.data)
            dispatch({
                type: POST_ADD_LIKE,
                payload: res.data
            })
            
        } catch (err) {
        
        }
    }
```

the API is working well and it does like the post , but my reducer does something else , here's the reducer:

```
case POST_ADD_LIKE:
            return {
                ...state,
                allPosts : state.allPosts.map(post => post._id === action.payload._id ? post.likes = post.likes+1 : post = post)
            }
```

(allPosts is the array of posts in my context state),

what my reducer does is replacing my whole object with '1' i guess its coming from the '+1' in the reducer , what i simply want is that the 'likes' property increments.
Anyone to help ! Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this

```js
allPosts: state.allPosts.map(post => post._id === action.payload._id ? { ...post, likes: post.likes+1 } : post);
```

Though I would say that formating it like this would make it a bit easier to read

```js
allPosts: state.allPosts.map(post => (
  ...post,
  likes: post.likes + (post._id === action.payload._id ? 1: 0),
)
```